# metasploit exploits and payloads documentation

Tags: exploit, metasploit, documentation

Where can i found the documentation of the exploits and payloads available in metasploit.

I am looking for a documentation that tells what does the exploit or the payload do, and possibly a description and how it works.

Comment: I would just search online for what I specifically need instead of trying to learn everything that can be done with Metasploit

Comment: When you select a module (exploit, payload etc), type info. OR https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/

Comment: that's what i was looking for, a sort of a manual, thanks for the info command bro, really sweeeeeeeeeeeet.

Comment: @void_in put your answer so i can choose it as the right one please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select a module such as exploit or payload in msfconsole, type the **info** command and it is going to show you the description of the module detailing what the module does. You can get the same information on the [rapid7's online module pages](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/) as well.

An example (taken from Offensive Security's Metasploit Unleashed is given below:

```
msf  exploit(ms09_050_smb2_negotiate_func_index) > info

       Name: Microsoft SRV2.SYS SMB Negotiate ProcessID Function Table Dereference
     Module: exploit/windows/smb/ms09_050_smb2_negotiate_func_index
    Version: 14774
   Platform: Windows
 Privileged: Yes
    License: Metasploit Framework License (BSD)
       Rank: Good

Provided by:
  Laurent Gaffie <laurent.gaffie@gmail.com>
  hdm <hdm@metasploit.com>
  sf <stephen_fewer@harmonysecurity.com>

Available targets:
  Id  Name
  --  ----
  0   Windows Vista SP1/SP2 and Server 2008 (x86)

Basic options:
  Name   Current Setting  Required  Description
  ----   ---------------  --------  -----------
  RHOST                   yes       The target address
  RPORT  445              yes       The target port
  WAIT   180              yes       The number of seconds to wait for the attack to complete.

Payload information:
  Space: 1024

Description:
  This module exploits an out of bounds function table dereference in 
  the SMB request validation code of the SRV2.SYS driver included with 
  Windows Vista, Windows 7 release candidates (not RTM), and Windows 
  2008 Server prior to R2. Windows Vista without SP1 does not seem 
  affected by this flaw.

References:
  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-050.mspx
  http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2009-3103
  http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/36299
  http://www.osvdb.org/57799
  http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2009/Sep/0039.html
  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/MS09-050.mspx

msf  exploit(ms09_050_smb2_negotiate_func_index) >
```

**Update**: Lately, Metasploit has started adding documentation to each of the module submitted and for the ones already included in the framework. These are available in the documentation directory under the same path as that of the exploit. For example, the documentation for the exploit module `exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi` can be found at `documentation/exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi.md`.

Answer (score 1):

Metasploit Unleashed (https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/) is some documentation that has information on what tools exist in the metasploit framework, what their purpose is and how to use them. It is written by Offensive Security, who are part of/fund Kali Linux.